# iOS - Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue crashed

Tags: ios, app-store, ipv6

App Store Connect is still rejecting my binary because of the crash with message:

Your app crashed on iPhone and iPad￼ running iOS 12.1.2 connected to an IPv6 network when we:

- Logged in with Facebook

And provided log says:

```
Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x283cdb4a0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
Thread 8 Crashed:
```

I am not able to reproduce this error on my device with iOS 12.1.2. Logging in with facebook works well for me, no crashes.

I have already found some possible solutions here on stack overflow and I tried to fix the issue using this code in places where it could cause this problem:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion:{

    }
}
```

I also tested my site if the IPv6 network testing is not the issue and this is the result:

[image]

Is this the problem? I cannot change server only because of that.

My binary was rejected again and I have no idea how to make it pass.

Comment: They should have provided a crashlog that you can symbolicate to identify where the crash is occurring.  The code you have shown is definitely wrong; UI operations needs to be performed on the main queue, not on a background queue. The IPv6 report you have shown is a fail for IPv6 connectivity to your site.  Have you tested your app on a pure IPv6 network?

Comment: OK. So it seems that it is IPv6 network issue. I need to test it myself. I also changed that code to DispatchQueue.main.async {}. Is that better? Because that was also rejected with the same issue.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct queue but the crash you are seeing won’t be caused by a UI background queue problem. Apple has a tech note on how to set up your Mac as a pure IPv6 network gateway for testing

Comment: adding to @Paulw11 answer, here is a link on how to configure IPv6 network gateway on mac: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html